# Attaching object to body in HttpRequest GET not working (dart, asp.net core)

Tags: asp.net-core, dart, httprequest

I'm currently using dart to communicate with an ASP.NET core web api. I'm able to do a simple get but I'm unable to do one with an object attached to the body. I AM able to do it in PostMan.

Here's a simple example I'm able to get working in Postman. It calls the appropriate entry point and return the right data.

```
Postman
GET: https://localhost:44389/api/people/param
BODY: RAW: { "age": "100" }
HEADERS(1): Content-Type:application/json
```

dart example

```
var vBody = json.encode(param.toJson()); // '{ "age": "100" }'
var vUri = Uri.https(WebConfig.serverAddress, '/api/people/param').toString();
var vMethod = 'GET';
var vHeaders = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }; 

print("vMethod: $vMethod");
print("vUri: $vUri");
print("vBody: $vBody");
print("vHeaders: $vHeaders");

await HttpRequest.request(
    vUri,
    method: vMethod,
    sendData: vBody,
    requestHeaders: vHeaders,

).then((resp) {
    print(resp.responseText);
}).catchError((Object error) {
    print(error.toString());
});
```

The dart comes back with 400 (Bad Request). I've been staring at this for hours. No idea why it's not working. It's possible dart has issues with passing body to GET methods.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, you shouldn't attach a body to a GET request, as it's not supposed to effect the result. The behaviour you're seeing is quite possibly by design.

Your parameters should just be baked into the URL, and then you just need to tell your ASP action how to respond. You can get ASP to parse out parameters from the URL itself.

Comment: You should add the query parameters in the URI constructor, ie: `Uri.https(address, path, vBody)`

Comment: The calls I'm making will require large complex objects being passed to the server. PostMan supports this (right or wrong) and the only way I can get it to work in Dart is to change it to a POST method which just seems wrong to me. Is there another way I  should be handling this?